# Methods for preventing SQL Injection in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, sql-injection

I'm wondering if the `#` symbol is enough.

This is a part of the sql command that I'm using

`WHERE login='#FORM.login#' AND password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = '#FORM.password#'`

I'm trying to test it with user names such as `' OR 1=1` and variants of it, but even though it's not working I don't want to have a false sense of security.

I've read that using `<cfqueryparam>` can prevent this form of attack, are there any other ways?

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.  You should hash your passwords using a secure salted hash (_not MD5_)

Comment: I agree, but it's not my database...

Comment: @Daniel: Nobody says the database structure must be changed, you can store a hash or a cleartext password in a VARCHAR, to the DB that's all the same. But storing a hash is smarter and much more secure *(or, put differently: storing cleartext passwords is incredibly dumb and dangerous)*. How long is the password field?

Comment: .. And not to sound unsympathetic, but developers still share responsibility for the security of information they handle whether it is their database or not.

Comment: I'm just writing a proposal for rewriting this application, while I might have to reword it, 'storing cleartext passwords is incredibly dumb and dangerous' is good fodder :)

Comment: It will certainly get attention, though maybe not the contract ... ;)

Comment: @Leigh Maybe this can be set into perspective with some LulzSec releases or so. ;) Just to show that things that *are* dumb sometimes also must be *called* dumb.

Comment: @Tomalak - Lol. A little demonstration is worth a thousand words? ;) "dumb" would probably seem more palatable after that.

Comment: @Leigh: I know that native English speakers tend to take it personally when you call something (not *them*!) dumb. But some bad habits just have to die, and this particular one is high on the list.

Comment: @Tomalak - Hey I actually would call this "dumb" (to the dismay of my boss I am sure ;) But I am curious about the native/non native speakers comment. I cannot say I have heard of that take. My limited experience is more you are either objective or you are not.

Comment: @Leigh. I'm German. A people not exactly praised for their subtlety and diplomacy in discussions. ;) I'm pretty direct (even for Germans). Having worked with Brits for a long time, I've learned that saying things the way they are upsets people, even if it's purely technical. It's less difficult with Americans, though. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak - Haha. I am in the US and find there are great differences in acceptable levels of bluntness even here. My current employer is more of a politician. But the previous one was like a freight train. He would call something dumb flat out. Then tack on a few extra descriptive terms just in case you missed it ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way to go is `<cfqueryparam>`. It's simple, straight-forward, datatype-safe, can handle lists (for use with `IN (...)`) and can handle conditional NULLs. Plus you get a benefit out of it in loops - the query text itself is sent to the server only once, with each further loop iteration only parameter values are transferred.

You can use `'#var#'` and be *relatively* safe. In the context of a `<cfquery>` tag ColdFusion will expand the value of `var` with single quotes escaped, so there is some kind of automatic defense against SQL injection. **But beware**: This will — by design — not happen with function return values: For example, in `'#Trim(var)#'` single quotes **won't** be escaped. This is easily overlooked and therefore dangerous.

Also, it has a disadvantage when run in a loop: Since variable interpolation happens *before* the SQL is sent to the server, ColdFusion will generate a new query text with every iteration of a loop. This means more bytes over the wire and no query plan caching on the server, as every query text is different.

In short: Use `<cfqueryparam>` wherever you can:

```
WHERE
  login        = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.login#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
  AND password = <cfqueryparam value='#Hash(FORM.password, "SHA-512")#' cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">
```

Instead of a simple [`Hash()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c52.html), you should indeed use a salted hash, as @SLaks pointed out in his comment.

Comment: +1 For the tip about functions. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score -1):

An even better way to go would be to use stored procedures for everything.

Comment: Stored Procedures have their uses, but not for everything. Queries and Stored Procedures should be used appropriately.

Comment: when building a coldfusion application, raw SQL literally has no place. it executes more slowly than stored procs and is open to injection if you use params without protection.